# A potential bug in this prioprity queue delMax() method, is it?

Tags: java, priority-queue

Here is a piece of Java code implementing delete the maximum value in a priority queue.

Problem is `Key max = pq[1]`, if `Key` is a primitive type, then this line really copy `pq[1]` into `max` variable. However, if `Key` is a reference, then after `exch()` and `sink()`, this `max` no longer reference to max value in this priority queue (it permanently references to pq[1]), but the second largest. Does what I think correct ?

```
 /**
 * Removes and returns a largest key on this priority queue.
 *
 * @return a largest key on this priority queue
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if this priority queue is empty
 */
public Key delMax() {
    if (isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Priority queue underflow");
    Key max = pq[1];
    exch(1, N--);
    sink(1);
    pq[N+1] = null;     // to avoid loiterig and help with garbage collection
    if ((N > 0) && (N == (pq.length - 1) / 4)) resize(pq.length / 2);
    assert isMaxHeap();
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `pq[1]` refers to some object somewhere else in the heap, and after `Key max = pq[1]`, `max` refers to that same object.  Changing `pq[1]` after that point does not change `max`.

Changing the *contents of the object referred to* by `pq[1]` would change the object referred to by `max`, since they're the same object, but just setting `pq[1]` to refer to a different object would not change `max`.

Comment: do you mean: `max` references to actuallyobject in heap. At the beginning, `pq[1]` and `max` reference to the same object in heap. Even though after `exch()` and `sink()`, `max` still reference to that object, whereas `pq[1]` references to another object in heap?